# How to count and separate consecutive heads or tails flips in java coin flip program?

Tags: java, loops

I'm trying to add spaces and a counter between consecutive runs in a simple java coin toss program.

I want this output: HHHHTHTTTTTTTHTTTHHHTTTTHTTHHHTTTTHHTHHHHHTTTTTTHT

to look print like this: HHHH4 T1 H1 TTTTTTT7  H1 TTT3 HHH3 TTTT4 H1 TT2 HHH3 TTTT4 HH2 T1 HHHHH5 TTTTTT6 H1 T1

I am not sure how to position the conditions in the loop so that spaces and a counter are printed between the consecutive 'T's and 'H's. Do I need to use a different kind of loop? I have tried rearranging the loop and using break; and continue; but haven't gotten the result to print correctly.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("How many times do you want to flip the coin? ");
    int timesFlipped = scnr.nextInt();
    Random randomNum = new Random();


    for (int i=0; i < timesFlipped; i++) {
        int currentflip = randomNum.nextInt(2);
        int previousFlip = 0;
        int tailsCount = 0;
        int headsCount = 0;

        if (currentflip == 0) {
            System.out.print("H");
            previousFlip = 0;
            headsCount++;
        }
        else if (currentflip == 1) {
            System.out.print("T");
            previousFlip = 1;
            tailsCount++;
        }

        if (previousFlip == 0 && currentflip == 1) {
            System.out.print(headsCount + " ");
            headsCount = 0;
        }
        else if (previousFlip == 1 && currentflip == 0) {
            System.out.print(tailsCount + " ");
            tailsCount = 0;
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, _a specific problem or error_ and _the shortest code necessary_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

You can just store the last flip and a counter like

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("How many times do you want to flip the coin? ");
    int timesFlipped = scnr.nextInt();
    Random randomNum = new Random();

    int counter = 1;
    int previousFlip = randomNum.nextInt(2);
    printFlip(previousFlip);
    for (int i=1; i < timesFlipped; i++) {
        int currentflip = randomNum.nextInt(2);
        if (currentflip == previousFlip) {
            counter++;
        } else {
            System.out.print(counter + " ");
            counter = 1;
            previousFlip = currentflip;
        }

        printFlip(currentflip);
    }
    System.out.print(counter);

}

private static void printFlip(int currentflip) {
    if (currentflip == 0) {
        System.out.print("H");
    }
    else if (currentflip == 1) {
        System.out.print("T");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Via a single method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("How many times do you want to flip the coin? ");
    int timesFlipped = scnr.nextInt();
    if (timesFlipped <= 0)
        return;

    Random randomNum = new Random();
    boolean isHeads = false;
    int sequence = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < timesFlipped; i++) {
        boolean prevFlip = isHeads;
        isHeads = randomNum.nextBoolean();
        if (i > 0 && isHeads != prevFlip) {
            System.out.print(sequence + " ");
            sequence = 0;
        }
        sequence++;
        System.out.print(isHeads ? "H" : "T");
    }

    System.out.println(sequence);
}
```